# How to provide heading of the mysql result set in the same result set

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to show the heading of the mysql resultset also in the output of my query(resultset).

For Eg:

```
Number of Exceptions:
ID|Region|Exception_count
1|India|100
2|China|300
3|US|500
```

Here Number of Exceptions is my heading, and the below to that is my query output.
I am thinking to provide a new column for heading, but it seems redundant data.

```
ID|Region|Exception_count|Heading
1|India|100|Number of Exceptions
2|China|300|Number of Exceptions
```

Could someone share thoughts on implementing this in a optimized way.

Comment: Add one more column to the output list, use literal value: `SELECT ID, Region, Exception_count, 'Number of Exceptions' Heading FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

Add a literal text column to the output, for example

```
SELECT ID, Region, Exception_count, 'Number of Exceptions' AS Heading FROM atable
```

Comment: This will solve but the amount of redundant data is increasing. So looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: That will provide your expected output, if you want to reduce the data then maybe move the 'Number of Exceptions' text out of the query and into whatever is using the query.

Comment: I didn't quite get it, what is meant by "move the 'Number of Exceptions' text out of the query and into whatever is using the query."

Comment: If you dont want the text 'Number of Exceptions' in the query then create it in whatever system is using the results of the query, application, web page, spreadsheet etc...

Comment: Got it @Mark B, But i'm looking for a solution other than adding a new column with fixed value as 'Number of Exceptions' in all rows.

Comment: That would depend on the context that the query is being used in, as I said generate the text outside the query, if you generate it in the query then it is in the query ... :)